# Time complexity of an Increment Function

Tags: algorithm

At our school, we had an exam. One of the questions was like this and asked for the worst case time-complexity of the following function:

> function(x){
> if(x%2==1)
> return 2*function( floor(x/2) );
> else
> return x+1
> }

I thought that this function had had a worst case O(logn).
Since, the recursion will be repeated until the number becomes even

The worst cases are with numbers that are 1 less than multiples of 2
In other words, numbers which come from 2^n -1

For example, for 7, recursion works 3 times
7 becomes 3
3 becomes 1
1 becomes 0

********** But spoiler ***********
Our teacher had said that the complexity is actually O(1) which was really confusing to me
If I am not mistaken, he said something like, “It’s O(1) since all the operations are actually constant”

What do you guys think? I am really curious to understand the answer

Comment: Maybe you can ask your teacher why your proof is wrong? At face value, the teacher's justification is nonsense and his/her conclusion wrong so perhaps there's a misunderstanding.

Comment: You labeled this question "c" and "data-structures" but the code is not in c, and no data-structures appear in the question.

Comment: For example, are you sure the question wasn't "what is the complexity of the function" rather than "what is the time complexity of the function"?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it to be kind of a trick question, because the operations that the function does are the following

1. Verify if `x` is odd
2. If `x` is odd then call the function and return the value
3. Otherwise, return `x + 1`

All these operations have a complexity of O(1).

This can be a bit confusing of course, because of the recursion, but the operation that the function does is calling itself which has a complexity of O(1).

So, if you had a version of this code using loops instead of recursion, yes it would be O(log n) in the worst case, but in this case its not.